# How do I setup a segue for a viewController to present itself

Tags: recursion, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue, recursive-datastructures

Ok, it's pretty simple with a storyboard to have one viewController create a segue to another viewController.  Simply control-click and drag from one viewController to the other.

How do I create a segue, either in the storyboard, or programmatically to invoke or present another instance of itself?

Why would I want to do this?

I currently have a viewController with a UICollectionView presented from data in a simple one-dimensional array of objects.  When I select an item it presents a detail viewController for that item.

What I want to do is modify my data for organizational reasons to allow the objects in the array to hold an array of objects like the original data array, as a folder with sub-folders. It seems reasonable to me that simply updating what the data source is pointing to, and calling the same viewController itself to display the next level should be relatively trivial.  When finished, simply pop back a level and be right where you left off.

It seems nontrivial to click-drag from the viewController to itself.  Prior to using storyboards and segues, this would be done by simply presenting the view contoller.  What is the best way to do this with storyboards and segues?

Yes, it COULD probably be done by manipulating the data source and just redrawing the current viewController, but it seems like it SHOULD be cleaner to just call the viewController with a pointer into the sub-array as if it was the top-level array and re-present the same viewController, letting the view controller stack manage the individual levels without having to redraw the model from different starting points and remembering the starting points in some kind of stack.

Any advice on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you cannot invoke or present your view controller on itself.
Likely this is because UIKit is not re-entrant or thread-safe.  So, Apple doesn't let you use a segue, or use presentViewController with an argument of self (or anything that resolves to self).

A pity, since it would have been nice to not have to create a sub-view contoller which does all the same things the viewController does.

If someone knows of a better way to do this, please post below.